# How to fix non iterable object in angular?

Tags: json, angular, rest

I am trying to consume webHdfs rest API to get the list of directories in a Hadoop cluster in an angular 7 App

I created the service

```
  public getHadoopDirList(): Observable<FileStatus[]> {
  return this.http.get<FileStatus[]>(this.webHdfsUrl, {}).pipe(map(data => data));
  }
```

and i subscribed to it like this

```
  loadHadoopDirList() {
   return this.restApi.getHadoopDirList().subscribe((data) => {
   this.hadoopDirList = data;
   console.log(data);
   }, error => {
    console.log(error);
   }
   );
   }
```

and here is the class that i used to parse the json:

```
export class FileStatus {
accessTime: number;
blockSize: number;
childNum: number;
fileId: number;
group: string;
length: number;
modificationTime: number;
owner: string;
pathSuffix: string;
permission: string;
replication: number;
storagePolicy: number;
type: string;
}
```

and here a pictures from the json response
[image]

and when I try to iterate over the result it shows 
**ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**

Comment: Please show your template code where you are looping

Comment: <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hadoopDir of hadoopDirList" >{{hadoopDir.pathSuffix}}</li>
</ul>

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<ul> <li *ngFor="let hadoopDir of hadoopDirList.fileStatus" >{{hadoopDir.pathSuffix}}</li> </ul>`

Comment: the error didn't show, but nothing appears on the HTML

Comment: It would be type: try: `*ngFor="let hadoopDir of hadoopDirList.FileStatus"`

Comment: I just discovered that hadoopDirList is empty, when I printed it in the console it is empty, what does that mean ?

Comment: List is empty? where did you add the console? under `subscribe()`? Did the revised solution not work for you?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.loadHadoopDirList();
    console.log('hadoopDir', this.hadoopDirList);
  } when loading it with the service it appear on the console, but when i print the list after calling the service it shows that it is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192630/discussion-between-xyz-and-achref-othmeni).

Answer (score 1):

Write the loop in your template like:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let hadoopDir of hadoopDirList?.FileStatuses?.FileStatus" >{{hadoopDir.pathSuffix}</li> 
</ul>
```